# Which rules apply when an argument of partial specialization does not use any of its template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization

> n4567 [temp.class.spec.match]p2
>
> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list (14.8.2).

```
template<class T, class U>
struct S{};

template<class U>
struct S<int, U>{};

S<char, int> s;
```

I know partial specialization `S<int, U>` do not match the actual template argument list `char, int`, and the second argument `U` can be deduced frome `int` accroding to 14.8.2.5.

But I don't know which rules in 14.8.2 apply for the first argument `int`.

> 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]p1
>
> Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but in each case **a type that is specified in terms of template parameters** (call it `P`) is compared with an actual type (call it `A`), and an attempt is made to find template argument values (a type for a type parameter, a value for a non-type parameter, or a template for a template parameter) that will make `P`, after substitution of the deduced values (call it the
>   deduced `A`), compatible with `A`.

In my understanding the `int` in `S<int, U>` is **not** specified in terms of template parameters, so 14.8.2.5 does **not** apply.

I want to know which rules handle this case or you can correct me about 14.8.2.5

---

In other words:
Intuitively, the partial specialization `S<int, U>` does not match `char,int` because `char` does not match `int`.

I want to know which rules determine `char` does not match `int`.

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: Also, you seem to have pretty substantially changed the substance of the question since you got the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering what happens here:

```
template<class T, class U> struct S{}; // (1)
template<class U> struct S<int, U>{};  // (2)

S<char, int> s; // (1) or (2)?
```

To determine which specialization we use for `s`, we go into [temp.class.spec.match]:

> When a class template is used in a context that requires an instantiation of the class, it is necessary to
>   determine whether the instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of the partial
>   specializations. This is done by matching the template arguments of the class template specialization with
>   the template argument lists of the partial specializations.

In this case, we're matching `<char, int>` against `<int, U>`. What does matches mean?

> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the
>   partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list (14.8.2).

Basically, we're deducing `U` to match `int == char` and `U == int`. Equivalently, we're looking at deducing `U` in:

```
template <class U> void f(S<int, U> );
f(S<char, int>{} );
```

There is no such deduction.

This leads us to:

> — If no matches are found, the instantiation is generated from the primary template.

That leads us to `(1)`.

Let's take a more interesting case:

```
S<int, char> s2;
```

Now, `<int, char>` matches against `<int, U>`, because we can deduce `U=char`. Hence:

> — If exactly one matching specialization is found, the instantiation is generated from that specialization.

That leads us to `(2)`.

Comment: Every deduction has `A` and `P`, what are they for `S<char, int>` matching `S<int, U>`?

Comment: @stackcpp `P` is `S<int, U>`. `A` is `S<char, int>`.

Comment: This makes sense. The standard says _if the **template arguments** of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list_, I thought the `A` was `int` and `P` was `U`, the deduction for `U` succeeded, but the match fails, so I asked this question.

Comment: @stackcpp Right, but the template arguments cannot be deduced because there's no `U` for which `S<int, U>` is `S<char, int>`.

Comment: If `P` is `S<int, U>`, `A` is `S<char, int>`, then the `14.5.5.1 p3` is redundant, because `14.8.2.5 p3.3` can handle this situation. See [Matching of class template partial specializations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32320293/4958516) and [What does “The template arguments of a specialization are deduced from the arguments of the primary template” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552056/what-does-the-template-arguments-of-a-specialization-are-deduced-from-the-argum)

Comment: @stackcpp p3 is about non-type arguments. Everything here is a type. Not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: See the example of [Matching of class template partial specializations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320293/matching-of-class-template-partial-specializations), `A<int, int*, 1>  a2;`, if the `A` is `A<int, int*, 1>`, and `P` is `A<T, T*, I>`, `14.5.5.1 p3` should be redundant. According to @Eugene Zavidovsky 's answer,  `I` can be deduced from `1` by p3, this implies there are three `P/A` pairs, not one.

Comment: If there is only one `P/A` pair, `14.8.2.5 p3.3` can handle non-type arguments, `14.5.5.1 p3` should be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

> In my understanding the int in S is not specified in terms of template parameters, so 14.8.2.5 does not apply.

No, `14.8.2.5` explains *how* to deduce the type, `14.3` deals with template arguments and the code you have posted fails `14.3p1`:

> 14.3p1
>   ... The type and form of each template-argument specified in a template-id shall match the type and form specified for the corresponding parameter declared by the template in its template parameter-list.

```
template<class T, class U>
struct S<int, U> {}; 
// compiler error, template parameters not used in partial specialization
```

should be

```
template<class U>
struct S<int, U> {};
```

So,

```
#1
template<class T, class U>
struct S{};

#2
template<class U>
struct S<int, U> {};

S<char, int> s; // uses #1
S<int, char> c; // uses #2 since S<int, U> matches more closely than S<T, U>
```

You mention that `gcc` rejected the template while `clang` accepted it. In my tests, `VC++` and `gcc` gave a compiler error by default and did not compile the code at all, `clang`, however, gave a warning instead stating that `this partial specialization will never be used` and built the binary anyways. So in all instances it's giving the notice of non-conformity, it's just a matter of what compiler settings are on by default and how the compiler implementation handles non-conforming code.

Hope that can help.

Comment: @stackcpp, yup, sorry about that, copy-pasta'd the wrong section. Should have been `14.3` .. a lot of the sections cross-reference each other and sometimes the sections need be read out of order to be read in order :/